# SwiftUI list not being displayed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchos

I just started learning SwiftUI and WatchOS, so playing with some list examples online to learn it. Eventually I wish to make a list with rows showing image on the left and text besides it on the right. My code below shows the frame of the row, but does not display the content on Watch simulator.

***ContentView Code:***

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State var selected: [MenuItem] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        MainMenuListView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

***MainMenuListView Code:***

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenuListView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                Text("Hello World")
                
                List {
                    Text("item.name")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .listRowPlatterColor(.clear)
                }.padding()

                // Example 2
//                List {
//                    Button(action: {}) { Text("Testing Testing") }
//                                .buttonStyle(BtnStyle(bgColor: .red, fgColor: .white))
//                                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets.init(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
//                                .listRowPlatterColor(.clear)
//                }.padding()
            }.navigationTitle("Sample Application")
        }
    }
}

struct MainMenuListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MainMenuListView()
    }
}

// Button Styles
struct BtnStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var bgColor: Color
    var fgColor: Color

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(fgColor)
            .background(bgColor)
            .cornerRadius(32)
    }
}
```

I will write the code to display image and text on a List row. But why is nothing
showing up in the simulator with the code I have? Here is how it looks on watch simulator.

[image]

Comment: List is scroll view itself, so throw ScrollView away and just move Text inside List (either directly or as section header).

Comment: Ah ok... you are right. That makes sense. Removing ScrollView worked. Thanks @Asperi!